# Pandas, Wide_to_Long is creating extra wrong rows and extra wrong column

Tags: python, pandas

I was doing some calculation in pandas and this is dataframe. First row is Column Names and Second row contains all the values.

When I converted this One rows to multiple rows using `pd.wide_to_long`, then it creates some extra wrong rows and columns. 
Example: there is only one Time with a Value of 1525063105767
but when i convert then I get more Time with a value of 1525063105767

Basically, `pd.wide_to_long` is creating extra rows using random values from existing Value. 
I am using this

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['Time','Longitude','Latitude','DateTime'],'ID', 'value', sep='', suffix='.+')\
    .reset_index()\
    .sort_values(['ID','Time'])\
    .drop('value', axis=1)\
    .dropna(how='any')
```

This my example dataframe

```
ID,Time.0,Latitude.0,Longitude.0,DateTime.0,Time.1,Latitude.1,Longitude.1,DateTime.1,Time.2,Latitude.2,Longitude.2,DateTime.2,Time.3,Latitude.3,Longitude.3,DateTime.3,Time.4,Latitude.4,Longitude.4,DateTime.4,Time.5,Latitude.5,Longitude.5,DateTime.5,Time.6,Latitude.6,Longitude.6,DateTime.6,Time.7,Latitude.7,Longitude.7,DateTime.7,Time.8,Latitude.8,Longitude.8,DateTime.8,Time.9,Latitude.9,Longitude.9,DateTime.9,Time.10,Latitude.10,Longitude.10,DateTime.10,Time.11,Latitude.11,Longitude.11,DateTime.11,Time.12,Latitude.12,Longitude.12,DateTime.12,Time.13,Latitude.13,Longitude.13,DateTime.13,Time.14,Latitude.14,Longitude.14,DateTime.14,Time.15,Latitude.15,Longitude.15,DateTime.15,Time.16,Latitude.16,Longitude.16,DateTime.16,Time.17,Latitude.17,Longitude.17,DateTime.17,Time.18,Latitude.18,Longitude.18,DateTime.18,Time.19,Latitude.19,Longitude.19,DateTime.19,Time.20,Latitude.20,Longitude.20,DateTime.20,Time.21,Latitude.21,Longitude.21,DateTime.21,Time.22,Latitude.22,Longitude.22,DateTime.22,Time.23,Latitude.23,Longitude.23,DateTime.23,Time.24,Latitude.24,Longitude.24,DateTime.24,Time.25,Latitude.25,Longitude.25,DateTime.25,Time.26,Latitude.26,Longitude.26,DateTime.26,Time.27,Latitude.27,Longitude.27,DateTime.27,Time.28,Latitude.28,Longitude.28,DateTime.28,Time.29,Latitude.29,Longitude.29,DateTime.29,Time.30,Latitude.30,Longitude.30,DateTime.30,Time.31,Latitude.31,Longitude.31,DateTime.31,Time.32,Latitude.32,Longitude.32,DateTime.32,Time.33,Latitude.33,Longitude.33,DateTime.33,Time.34,Latitude.34,Longitude.34,DateTime.34,Time.35,Latitude.35,Longitude.35,DateTime.35,Time.36,Latitude.36,Longitude.36,DateTime.36,Time.37,Latitude.37,Longitude.37,DateTime.37,Time.38,Latitude.38,Longitude.38,DateTime.38,Time.39,Latitude.39,Longitude.39,DateTime.39,Time.40,Latitude.40,Longitude.40,DateTime.40,Time.41,Latitude.41,Longitude.41,DateTime.41,Time.42,Latitude.42,Longitude.42,DateTime.42,Time.43,Latitude.43,Longitude.43,DateTime.43,Time.44,Latitude.44,Longitude.44,DateTime.44,Time.45,Latitude.45,Longitude.45,DateTime.45,Time.46,Latitude.46,Longitude.46,DateTime.46,Time.47,Latitude.47,Longitude.47,DateTime.47,Time.48,Latitude.48,Longitude.48,DateTime.48,Time.49,Latitude.49,Longitude.49,DateTime.49,Time.50,Latitude.50,Longitude.50,DateTime.50,Time.51,Latitude.51,Longitude.51,DateTime.51,Time.52,Latitude.52,Longitude.52,DateTime.52,Time.53,Latitude.53,Longitude.53,DateTime.53,Time.54,Latitude.54,Longitude.54,DateTime.54,Time.55,Latitude.55,Longitude.55,DateTime.55,Time.56,Latitude.56,Longitude.56,DateTime.56,Time.57,Latitude.57,Longitude.57,DateTime.57,Time.58,Latitude.58,Longitude.58,DateTime.58,Time.59,Latitude.59,Longitude.59,DateTime.59,Time.60,Latitude.60,Longitude.60,DateTime.60,Time.61,Latitude.61,Longitude.61,DateTime.61,Time.62,Latitude.62,Longitude.62,DateTime.62,Time.63,Latitude.63,Longitude.63,DateTime.63,Time.64,Latitude.64,Longitude.64,DateTime.64,Time.65,Latitude.65,Longitude.65,DateTime.65,Time.66,Latitude.66,Longitude.66,DateTime.66,Time.67,Latitude.67,Longitude.67,DateTime.67,Time.68,Latitude.68,Longitude.68,DateTime.68,Time.69,Latitude.69,Longitude.69,DateTime.69,Time.70,Latitude.70,Longitude.70,DateTime.70,Time.71,Latitude.71,Longitude.71,DateTime.71,Time.72,Latitude.72,Longitude.72,DateTime.72,Time.73,Latitude.73,Longitude.73,DateTime.73,Time.74,Latitude.74,Longitude.74,DateTime.74,Time.75,Latitude.75,Longitude.75,DateTime.75,Time.76,Latitude.76,Longitude.76,DateTime.76,Time.77,Latitude.77,Longitude.77,DateTime.77,Time.78,Latitude.78,Longitude.78,DateTime.78,Time.79,Latitude.79,Longitude.79,DateTime.79,Time.80,Latitude.80,Longitude.80,DateTime.80,Time.81,Latitude.81,Longitude.81,DateTime.81,Time.82,Latitude.82,Longitude.82,DateTime.82,Time.83,Latitude.83,Longitude.83,DateTime.83,Time.84,Latitude.84,Longitude.84,DateTime.84,Time.85,Latitude.85,Longitude.85,DateTime.85,Time.86,Latitude.86,Longitude.86,DateTime.86,Time.87,Latitude.87,Longitude.87,DateTime.87,Time.88,Latitude.88,Longitude.88,DateTime.88,Time.89,Latitude.89,Longitude.89,DateTime.89,Time.90,Latitude.90,Longitude.90,DateTime.90,Time.91,Latitude.91,Longitude.91,DateTime.91,Time.92,Latitude.92,Longitude.92,DateTime.92,Time.93,Latitude.93,Longitude.93,DateTime.93,Time.94,Latitude.94,Longitude.94,DateTime.94,Time.95,Latitude.95,Longitude.95,DateTime.95,Time.96,Latitude.96,Longitude.96,DateTime.96,Time.97,Latitude.97,Longitude.97,DateTime.97,Time.98,Latitude.98,Longitude.98,DateTime.98,Time.99,Latitude.99,Longitude.99,DateTime.99,Time.100,Latitude.100,Longitude.100,DateTime.100,Time.101,Latitude.101,Longitude.101,DateTime.101,Time.102,Latitude.102,Longitude.102,DateTime.102,Time.103,Latitude.103,Longitude.103,DateTime.103,Time.104,Latitude.104,Longitude.104,DateTime.104,Time.105,Latitude.105,Longitude.105,DateTime.105,Time.106,Latitude.106,Longitude.106,DateTime.106,Time.107,Latitude.107,Longitude.107,DateTime.107,Time.108,Latitude.108,Longitude.108,DateTime.108,Time.109,Latitude.109,Longitude.109,DateTime.109,Time.110,Latitude.110,Longitude.110,DateTime.110,Time.111,Latitude.111,Longitude.111,DateTime.111,Time.112,Latitude.112,Longitude.112,DateTime.112,Time.113,Latitude.113,Longitude.113,DateTime.113,Time.114,Latitude.114,Longitude.114,DateTime.114,Time.115,Latitude.115,Longitude.115,DateTime.115,Time.116,Latitude.116,Longitude.116,DateTime.116,Time.117,Latitude.117,Longitude.117,DateTime.117,Time.118,Latitude.118,Longitude.118,DateTime.118,Time.119,Latitude.119,Longitude.119,DateTime.119,Time.120,Latitude.120,Longitude.120,DateTime.120,Time.121,Latitude.121,Longitude.121,DateTime.121,Time.122,Latitude.122,Longitude.122,DateTime.122,Time.123,Latitude.123,Longitude.123,DateTime.123,Time.124,Latitude.124,Longitude.124,DateTime.124,Time.125,Latitude.125,Longitude.125,DateTime.125,Time.126,Latitude.126,Longitude.126,DateTime.126,Time.127,Latitude.127,Longitude.127,DateTime.127,Time.128,Latitude.128,Longitude.128,DateTime.128,Time.129,Latitude.129,Longitude.129,DateTime.129,Time.130,Latitude.130,Longitude.130,DateTime.130,Time.131,Latitude.131,Longitude.131,DateTime.131,Time.132,Latitude.132,Longitude.132,DateTime.132,Time.133,Latitude.133,Longitude.133,DateTime.133,Time.134,Latitude.134,Longitude.134,DateTime.134,Time.135,Latitude.135,Longitude.135,DateTime.135,Time.136,Latitude.136,Longitude.136,DateTime.136,Time.137,Latitude.137,Longitude.137,DateTime.137,Time.138,Latitude.138,Longitude.138,DateTime.138,Time.139,Latitude.139,Longitude.139,DateTime.139,Time.140,Latitude.140,Longitude.140,DateTime.140,Time.141,Latitude.141,Longitude.141,DateTime.141,Time.142,Latitude.142,Longitude.142,DateTime.142,Time.143,Latitude.143,Longitude.143,DateTime.143,Time.144,Latitude.144,Longitude.144,DateTime.144,Time.145,Latitude.145,Longitude.145,DateTime.145,Time.146,Latitude.146,Longitude.146,DateTime.146,Time.147,Latitude.147,Longitude.147,DateTime.147,Time.148,Latitude.148,Longitude.148,DateTime.148,Time.149,Latitude.149,Longitude.149,DateTime.149,Time.150,Latitude.150,Longitude.150,DateTime.150,Time.151,Latitude.151,Longitude.151,DateTime.151,Time.152,Latitude.152,Longitude.152,DateTime.152,Time.153,Latitude.153,Longitude.153,DateTime.153,Time.154,Latitude.154,Longitude.154,DateTime.154,Time.155,Latitude.155,Longitude.155,DateTime.155,Time.156,Latitude.156,Longitude.156,DateTime.156,Time.157,Latitude.157,Longitude.157,DateTime.157,Time.158,Latitude.158,Longitude.158,DateTime.158,Time.159,Latitude.159,Longitude.159,DateTime.159,Time.160,Latitude.160,Longitude.160,DateTime.160,Time.161,Latitude.161,Longitude.161,DateTime.161,Time.162,Latitude.162,Longitude.162,DateTime.162,Time.163,Latitude.163,Longitude.163,DateTime.163,Time.164,Latitude.164,Longitude.164,DateTime.164,Time.165,Latitude.165,Longitude.165,DateTime.165,Time.166,Latitude.166,Longitude.166,DateTime.166,Time.167,Latitude.167,Longitude.167,DateTime.167,Time.168,Latitude.168,Longitude.168,DateTime.168,Time.169,Latitude.169,Longitude.169,DateTime.169,Time.170,Latitude.170,Longitude.170,DateTime.170,Time.171,Latitude.171,Longitude.171,DateTime.171,Time.172,Latitude.172,Longitude.172,DateTime.172,Time.173,Latitude.173,Longitude.173,DateTime.173,Time.174,Latitude.174,Longitude.174,DateTime.174,Time.175,Latitude.175,Longitude.175,DateTime.175,Time.176,Latitude.176,Longitude.176,DateTime.176,Time.177,Latitude.177,Longitude.177,DateTime.177,Time.178,Latitude.178,Longitude.178,DateTime.178,Time.179,Latitude.179,Longitude.179,DateTime.179,Time.180,Latitude.180,Longitude.180,DateTime.180,Time.181,Latitude.181,Longitude.181,DateTime.181,Time.182,Latitude.182,Longitude.182,DateTime.182,Time.183,Latitude.183,Longitude.183,DateTime.183,Time.184,Latitude.184,Longitude.184,DateTime.184,Time.185,Latitude.185,Longitude.185,DateTime.185,Time.186,Latitude.186,Longitude.186,DateTime.186,Time.187,Latitude.187,Longitude.187,DateTime.187,Time.188,Latitude.188,Longitude.188,DateTime.188,Time.189,Latitude.189,Longitude.189,DateTime.189,Time.190,Latitude.190,Longitude.190,DateTime.190,Time.191,Latitude.191,Longitude.191,DateTime.191,Time.192,Latitude.192,Longitude.192,DateTime.192,Time.193,Latitude.193,Longitude.193,DateTime.193,Time.194,Latitude.194,Longitude.194,DateTime.194,Time.195,Latitude.195,Longitude.195,DateTime.195,Time.196,Latitude.196,Longitude.196,DateTime.196,Time.197,Latitude.197,Longitude.197,DateTime.197,Time.198,Latitude.198,Longitude.198,DateTime.198,Time.199,Latitude.199,Longitude.199,DateTime.199,Time.200,Latitude.200,Longitude.200,DateTime.200,Time.201,Latitude.201,Longitude.201,DateTime.201,Time.202,Latitude.202,Longitude.202,DateTime.202,Time.203,Latitude.203,Longitude.203,DateTime.203,Time.204,Latitude.204,Longitude.204,DateTime.204,Time.205,Latitude.205,Longitude.205,DateTime.205,Time.206,Latitude.206,Longitude.206,DateTime.206,Time.207,Latitude.207,Longitude.207,DateTime.207,Time.208,Latitude.208,Longitude.208,DateTime.208,Time.209,Latitude.209,Longitude.209,DateTime.209,Time.210,Latitude.210,Longitude.210,DateTime.210,Time.211,Latitude.211,Longitude.211,DateTime.211,Time.212,Latitude.212,Longitude.212,DateTime.212,Time.213,Latitude.213,Longitude.213,DateTime.213,Time.214,Latitude.214,Longitude.214,DateTime.214,Time.215,Latitude.215,Longitude.215,DateTime.215,Time.216,Latitude.216,Longitude.216,DateTime.216,Time.217,Latitude.217,Longitude.217,DateTime.217,Time.218,Latitude.218,Longitude.218,DateTime.218,Time.219,Latitude.219,Longitude.219,DateTime.219,Time.220,Latitude.220,Longitude.220,DateTime.220,Time.221,Latitude.221,Longitude.221,DateTime.221,Time.222,Latitude.222,Longitude.222,DateTime.222
230629000,2018-04-29 18:19:52,60.41086666666667,22.126466666666666,1525025992194.0,2018-04-29 18:29:58,60.37578333333333,22.10035,1525026598817.0,2018-04-29 18:39:54,60.3283,22.0595,1525027194504.0,2018-04-29 18:49:53,60.27985,21.9946,1525027793922.0,2018-04-29 18:59:54,60.26046666666666,21.88255,1525028394797.0,2018-04-29 19:09:53,60.232883333333334,21.780883333333332,1525028993157.0,2018-04-29 19:19:55,60.21693333333334,21.67156666666667,1525029595623.0,2018-04-29 19:29:53,60.20630000000001,21.56465,1525030193361.0,2018-04-29 19:39:53,60.18466666666666,21.482416666666666,1525030793578.0,2018-04-29 19:49:54,60.16205,21.40375,1525031394793.0,2018-04-29 19:59:25,60.13228333333333,21.330166666666667,1525031965964.0,2018-04-29 20:09:55,60.10655,21.241433333333333,1525032595881.0,2018-04-29 20:19:53,60.09013333333333,21.14905,1525033193070.0,2018-04-29 20:29:55,60.08093333333333,21.053283333333333,1525033795465.0,2018-04-29 20:39:52,60.08035,20.956133333333334,1525034392768.0,2018-04-29 20:49:55,60.07885,20.860816666666665,1525034995950.0,2018-04-29 20:59:55,60.09171666666667,20.767983333333333,1525035595264.0,2018-04-29 21:09:54,60.09693333333333,20.67526666666668,1525036194205.0,2018-04-29 21:19:53,60.12535000000001,20.596016666666667,1525036793681.0,2018-04-29 21:29:55,60.11533333333333,20.509383333333336,1525037395319.0,2018-04-29 21:39:55,60.10276666666667,20.43028333333333,1525037995625.0,2018-04-29 21:49:54,60.11396666666667,20.34215,1525038594500.0,2018-04-29 21:59:57,60.11515,20.3049,1525039197248.0,2018-04-29 22:09:57,60.1157,20.303466666666672,1525039797739.0,2018-04-29 22:19:57,60.08041666666666,20.31855,1525040397865.0,2018-04-29 22:29:56,60.03656666666666,20.3063,1525040996075.0,2018-04-29 22:39:57,59.99398333333333,20.267,1525041597827.0,2018-04-29 22:49:57,59.94966666666666,20.2194,1525042197305.0,2018-04-29 22:59:57,59.96616666666666,20.137366666666665,1525042797302.0,2018-04-29 23:09:56,59.97043333333333,20.04145,1525043396478.0,2018-04-29 23:19:55,59.94405,19.950433333333333,1525043995515.0,2018-04-29 23:29:55,59.91373333333333,19.849983333333334,1525044595721.0,2018-04-29 23:39:57,59.88333333333333,19.749366666666667,1525045197191.0,2018-04-29 23:49:57,59.85310000000001,19.64895,1525045797495.0,2018-04-29 23:59:57,59.82288333333334,19.549066666666665,1525046397354.0,2018-04-30 00:09:55,59.79318333333333,19.449066666666667,1525046995298.0,2018-04-30 00:19:56,59.76451666666666,19.347583333333333,1525047596211.0,2018-04-30 00:29:57,59.7431,19.238816666666665,1525048197705.0,2018-04-30 00:39:58,59.72506666666666,19.135033333333336,1525048798434.0,2018-04-30 00:49:58,59.70238333333334,19.045916666666667,1525049398035.0,2018-04-30 00:59:51,59.67736666666666,18.9654,1525049991987.0,2018-04-30 01:09:57,59.65826666666667,18.920366666666666,1525050597469.0,2018-04-30 01:19:54,59.64158333333333,18.8813,1525051194367.0,2018-04-30 01:29:55,59.61586666666667,18.81855,1525051795569.0,2018-04-30 01:39:51,59.58966666666666,18.74595,1525052391053.0,2018-04-30 01:49:55,59.57156666666666,18.66625,1525052995863.0,2018-04-30 01:59:58,59.55703333333334,18.616133333333334,1525053598237.0,2018-04-30 02:03:00,59.55238333333333,18.60245,1525053780897.0,2018-04-30 02:18:19,59.5273,18.53535,1525054699645.0,2018-04-30 02:27:58,59.51081666666666,18.494316666666673,1525055278620.0,2018-04-30 02:37:56,59.48863333333334,18.454883333333328,1525055876822.0,2018-04-30 02:49:53,59.4434,18.411866666666665,1525056593299.0,2018-04-30 02:57:42,59.42135,18.400916666666667,1525057062072.0,2018-04-30 03:19:59,59.35748333333333,18.428800000000006,1525058399247.0,2018-04-30 03:26:04,59.36528333333333,18.402933333333333,1525058764317.0,2018-04-30 03:39:21,59.37758333333333,18.322516666666672,1525059561744.0,2018-04-30 03:43:03,59.37835,18.29185,1525059783947.0,2018-04-30 04:09:27,59.31973333333334,18.136216666666666,1525061367496.0,2018-04-30 04:11:16,59.31928333333334,18.12796666666668,1525061476256.0,2018-04-30 04:25:06,59.31705,18.094866666666668,1525062306164.0,2018-04-30 04:38:25,59.31701666666667,18.09488333333333,1525063105767.0,2018-04-30 04:47:28,59.31701666666667,18.094866666666668,1525063648303.0,2018-04-30 04:59:55,59.31701666666667,18.09488333333333,1525064395796.0,2018-04-30 05:09:59,59.31701666666667,18.09488333333333,1525064999200.0,2018-04-30 05:15:17,59.31703333333334,18.0949,1525065317886.0,2018-04-30 05:29:56,59.31701666666667,18.094866666666668,1525066196185.0,2018-04-30 05:34:25,59.31701666666667,18.094866666666668,1525066465433.0,2018-04-30 05:49:47,59.31945,18.12985,1525067387834.0,2018-04-30 06:00:00,59.32738333333334,18.1853,1525068000246.0
```

This is the output

```
ID,Time,Longitude,Latitude,DateTime
230629000,2018-04-29 18:19:52,22.126466666666666,60.41086666666667,1525025992194.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,22.10035,60.37578333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,22.10035,60.37578333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,22.10035,60.13228333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,22.10035,60.13228333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,21.330166666666667,60.37578333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,21.330166666666667,60.37578333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,21.330166666666667,60.13228333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:29:58,21.330166666666667,60.13228333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,22.0595,60.3283,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,22.0595,60.3283,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,22.0595,60.10276666666667,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,22.0595,60.10276666666667,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,20.43028333333333,60.3283,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,20.43028333333333,60.3283,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,20.43028333333333,60.10276666666667,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:39:54,20.43028333333333,60.10276666666667,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,21.9946,60.27985,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,21.9946,60.27985,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,21.9946,59.94405,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,21.9946,59.94405,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,19.950433333333333,60.27985,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,19.950433333333333,60.27985,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,19.950433333333333,59.94405,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:49:53,19.950433333333333,59.94405,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,21.88255,60.26046666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,21.88255,60.26046666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,21.88255,59.67736666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,21.88255,59.67736666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,18.9654,60.26046666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,18.9654,60.26046666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,18.9654,59.67736666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-29 18:59:54,18.9654,59.67736666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,21.780883333333332,60.232883333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,21.780883333333332,60.232883333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,21.780883333333332,59.48863333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,21.780883333333332,59.48863333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,18.454883333333328,60.232883333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,18.454883333333328,60.232883333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,18.454883333333328,59.48863333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:09:53,18.454883333333328,59.48863333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,21.67156666666667,60.21693333333334,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,21.67156666666667,60.21693333333334,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,21.67156666666667,59.31701666666667,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,21.67156666666667,59.31701666666667,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,18.09488333333333,60.21693333333334,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,18.09488333333333,60.21693333333334,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,18.09488333333333,59.31701666666667,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:19:55,18.09488333333333,59.31701666666667,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:29:53,21.56465,60.20630000000001,1525030193361.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:39:53,21.482416666666666,60.18466666666666,1525030793578.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:49:54,21.40375,60.16205,1525031394793.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,22.10035,60.37578333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,22.10035,60.37578333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,22.10035,60.13228333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,22.10035,60.13228333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,21.330166666666667,60.37578333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,21.330166666666667,60.37578333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,21.330166666666667,60.13228333333333,1525026598817.0
230629000,2018-04-29 19:59:25,21.330166666666667,60.13228333333333,1525031965964.0
230629000,2018-04-29 20:09:55,21.241433333333333,60.10655,1525032595881.0
230629000,2018-04-29 20:19:53,21.14905,60.09013333333333,1525033193070.0
230629000,2018-04-29 20:29:55,21.053283333333333,60.08093333333333,1525033795465.0
230629000,2018-04-29 20:39:52,20.956133333333334,60.08035,1525034392768.0
230629000,2018-04-29 20:49:55,20.860816666666665,60.07885,1525034995950.0
230629000,2018-04-29 20:59:55,20.767983333333333,60.09171666666667,1525035595264.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:09:54,20.67526666666668,60.09693333333333,1525036194205.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:19:53,20.596016666666667,60.12535000000001,1525036793681.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:29:55,20.509383333333336,60.11533333333333,1525037395319.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,22.0595,60.3283,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,22.0595,60.3283,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,22.0595,60.10276666666667,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,22.0595,60.10276666666667,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,20.43028333333333,60.3283,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,20.43028333333333,60.3283,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,20.43028333333333,60.10276666666667,1525027194504.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:39:55,20.43028333333333,60.10276666666667,1525037995625.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:49:54,20.34215,60.11396666666667,1525038594500.0
230629000,2018-04-29 21:59:57,20.3049,60.11515,1525039197248.0
230629000,2018-04-29 22:09:57,20.303466666666672,60.1157,1525039797739.0
230629000,2018-04-29 22:19:57,20.31855,60.08041666666666,1525040397865.0
230629000,2018-04-29 22:29:56,20.3063,60.03656666666666,1525040996075.0
230629000,2018-04-29 22:39:57,20.267,59.99398333333333,1525041597827.0
230629000,2018-04-29 22:49:57,20.2194,59.94966666666666,1525042197305.0
230629000,2018-04-29 22:59:57,20.137366666666665,59.96616666666666,1525042797302.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:09:56,20.04145,59.97043333333333,1525043396478.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,21.9946,60.27985,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,21.9946,60.27985,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,21.9946,59.94405,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,21.9946,59.94405,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,19.950433333333333,60.27985,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,19.950433333333333,60.27985,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,19.950433333333333,59.94405,1525027793922.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:19:55,19.950433333333333,59.94405,1525043995515.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:29:55,19.849983333333334,59.91373333333333,1525044595721.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:39:57,19.749366666666667,59.88333333333333,1525045197191.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:49:57,19.64895,59.85310000000001,1525045797495.0
230629000,2018-04-29 23:59:57,19.549066666666665,59.82288333333334,1525046397354.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:09:55,19.449066666666667,59.79318333333333,1525046995298.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:19:56,19.347583333333333,59.76451666666666,1525047596211.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:29:57,19.238816666666665,59.7431,1525048197705.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:39:58,19.135033333333336,59.72506666666666,1525048798434.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:49:58,19.045916666666667,59.70238333333334,1525049398035.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,21.88255,60.26046666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,21.88255,60.26046666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,21.88255,59.67736666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,21.88255,59.67736666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,18.9654,60.26046666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,18.9654,60.26046666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,18.9654,59.67736666666666,1525028394797.0
230629000,2018-04-30 00:59:51,18.9654,59.67736666666666,1525049991987.0
230629000,2018-04-30 01:09:57,18.920366666666666,59.65826666666667,1525050597469.0
230629000,2018-04-30 01:19:54,18.8813,59.64158333333333,1525051194367.0
230629000,2018-04-30 01:29:55,18.81855,59.61586666666667,1525051795569.0
230629000,2018-04-30 01:39:51,18.74595,59.58966666666666,1525052391053.0
230629000,2018-04-30 01:49:55,18.66625,59.57156666666666,1525052995863.0
230629000,2018-04-30 01:59:58,18.616133333333334,59.55703333333334,1525053598237.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:03:00,18.60245,59.55238333333333,1525053780897.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:18:19,18.53535,59.5273,1525054699645.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:27:58,18.494316666666673,59.51081666666666,1525055278620.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,21.780883333333332,60.232883333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,21.780883333333332,60.232883333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,21.780883333333332,59.48863333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,21.780883333333332,59.48863333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,18.454883333333328,60.232883333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,18.454883333333328,60.232883333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,18.454883333333328,59.48863333333334,1525028993157.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:37:56,18.454883333333328,59.48863333333334,1525055876822.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:49:53,18.411866666666665,59.4434,1525056593299.0
230629000,2018-04-30 02:57:42,18.400916666666667,59.42135,1525057062072.0
230629000,2018-04-30 03:19:59,18.428800000000006,59.35748333333333,1525058399247.0
230629000,2018-04-30 03:26:04,18.402933333333333,59.36528333333333,1525058764317.0
230629000,2018-04-30 03:39:21,18.322516666666672,59.37758333333333,1525059561744.0
230629000,2018-04-30 03:43:03,18.29185,59.37835,1525059783947.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:09:27,18.136216666666666,59.31973333333334,1525061367496.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:11:16,18.12796666666668,59.31928333333334,1525061476256.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:25:06,18.094866666666668,59.31705,1525062306164.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,21.67156666666667,60.21693333333334,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,21.67156666666667,60.21693333333334,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,21.67156666666667,59.31701666666667,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,21.67156666666667,59.31701666666667,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,18.09488333333333,60.21693333333334,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,18.09488333333333,60.21693333333334,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,18.09488333333333,59.31701666666667,1525029595623.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:38:25,18.09488333333333,59.31701666666667,1525063105767.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:47:28,18.094866666666668,59.31701666666667,1525063648303.0
230629000,2018-04-30 04:59:55,18.09488333333333,59.31701666666667,1525064395796.0
230629000,2018-04-30 05:09:59,18.09488333333333,59.31701666666667,1525064999200.0
230629000,2018-04-30 05:15:17,18.0949,59.31703333333334,1525065317886.0
230629000,2018-04-30 05:29:56,18.094866666666668,59.31701666666667,1525066196185.0
230629000,2018-04-30 05:34:25,18.094866666666668,59.31701666666667,1525066465433.0
230629000,2018-04-30 05:49:47,18.12985,59.31945,1525067387834.0
230629000,2018-04-30 06:00:00,18.1853,59.32738333333334,1525068000246.0
```

Any idea,why this is happening. As you can see there are some of the multiple extra rows which was made from existing rows using the random values from random rows.

Comment: care to cut down to example? to something minimsl, please

Comment: I am sorry but it  was necessary to post all data information, to show that it is not calculating properly

Comment: I see, it looks bettter on desktop, just too bad on an smartphone.

Comment: can you make creation of your sample dataframe a pastable, runnable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any metric of success that you can apply? Eg. some `assert` statement 
that would assure the result is correct?

I have the following change to code, but not sure the result is satisfactory:

```
# lets change suffix and separator 
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      ['Time','Longitude','Latitude','DateTime'],
                      i='ID', 
                      j='value', 
                      sep='.', 
                      suffix='\\d+')\
    .reset_index()\
    .sort_values(['ID','Time'])\
    # I think 'values' are important to your dataset, why drop them?            
    #.drop('value', axis=1)\
    # There are not na's is the example
    #.dropna(how='any')
```

Comment: great, the problem was with suffix and sep. and about dropna and value, I have to remove those as I dont want extra column called value and I will have lots of NaN as this was just a sample.

Comment: removing value is safe to do as long as ID column is meaningful and suits, otherwise it felt like loosing some information. glad it worked!